# An abelian group with odd number of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that G is an Abelian group with an odd number of elements.
Show that the product of all of the elements of G is the identity.

I just need a hint to start. I don't know how to start

Answer (score 2):

The only element $x$ of $G$ equal to its inverse i.e. $x^2=e$ is $e$. Why? so the product of all the elements of $G$ is the product of every element with its inverse... Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! I got it. To explain more, if there exists an element rather than the identity to have an order of 2, then the whole group should be even and that's a contradiction! :)

Comment: Yes that's correct using the Lagrange theorem. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange’s theorem, no element of $G$ can have order two (two doesn’t divide an odd number) so no element is its own inverse. Inverses are also unique and thus writing $|G| = 2n+ 1$ we can choose distinct elements $g_1, \dots , g_n \in G$ such that $G = \{e, g_1, g_1^{ −1} ,\dots , g_n, g_n^{ −1}\}$ (the implication being that $\{e, g_1, g_1^{ −1} ,\dots , g_n, g_n^{ −1}\}$  are the distinct elements of G). Now it is clear that the product of all the elements of G gives the identity, that is, that $eg_1g_1^{ −1} g_2g_2^{ −1}\cdots g_ng_n^{ −1} = e.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think about inverses of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping the elements in to pairs, $a$ and $a^{-1}$.